# Robocopy not seeing new files if in the middle of copying a file

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

Doing some testing with robocopy on Windows 7 from local disk to a USB stick with this command (mostly copied from another post):

ROBOCOPY c:\RC_Source d:\RC_Dest /E /ZB /XJ /XF "~*.*" "*~.*" "desktop.ini" "Thumbs.db" ".lock" ".Sync*" /xd "Rubbish" ".Sync*" ".Box Sync" "_private" "Outlook Files" /FFT /R:2 /W:5 /V /MON:1 /LOG:robocopy.log  /TEE

It seems to work OK, but if robocopy is in the middle of copying a file and I paste another file into the same directory it doesn't get copied after it has finished the last file or when it monitors for file / directory changes. If while robocopy is waiting for changes I then copy another file into the source directory then it will copy both files. alternatively if I kill the robocopy command and start it again then it will copy the file.

Is there any way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: `/mon:<N>` [Monitors the source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx), and runs again when **more than `N` changes** are detected. . Try `/MON:0`.

Comment: @JosefZ `/MON:0` has the effect of turning off monitoring even though the help would suggest otherwise. `/MON:1` does pickup single changes, but seems to miss me even copying in a whole directory of stuff into the source folder if it is in the middle of copying something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct fix AFAIK, but I think that the following powershell script is probably the simplest way of dealing with it:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    robocopy <sourcedir> <destdir> /MOV /MON:1
}

while (1) {
    try {Get-ChildItem <sourcedir> | Foreach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date}}
    catch{}
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

Add logic to end the job gracefully if needed.